# Difficult Subtraction of Elements in Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have the following dataframe:

```
     CA  UNIT      SCP     DATE     TIME    DESC ENTRIES   EXITS 
   (chr) (chr)    (chr)    (chr)    (chr)   (chr)   (dbl)   (dbl)  
1   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-10-13 04:00:00 REGULAR 4026243 1386869 
2   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-10-13 08:00:00 REGULAR 4026273 1386886 
3   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-10-13 12:00:00 REGULAR 4026382 1386951 
4   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-10-13 16:00:00 REGULAR 4026612 1387002 
5   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-10-13 20:00:00 REGULAR 4026878 1387051 
6   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-11-13 00:00:00 REGULAR 4026955 1387080
7   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-11-13 04:00:00 REGULAR 4026972 1387082
8   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-11-13 08:00:00 REGULAR 4027014 1387182
9   A002  R051 02-00-00 03-11-13 12:00:00 REGULAR 4027189 1387473
10  A002  R051 02-00-00 03-11-13 16:00:00 REGULAR 4027413 1387547
```

I am trying to calculate Entries for each 4 hour time frame.  So, the number of entries between 04:00:00 and 08:00:00 is 4026273 - 4026243. I need to calculate these diffrence all the way down the column.  I've been trying to figure a way but I'm at a loss.

I need to do this for each DATE and SCP.

Is there a way to cast TIME so each 4 hour time frame becomes a column?  I tried that route but had errors (presumably because I have duplicate columns in CA UNIT SCP and DATE

I've also been trying to figure it out using dplyr group_by and summarise.  I'm stuck.

I keep thinking that there is an easy way to solve this problem but it is escaping me.  Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Your time column is already 4 hour differences.  If that is the case then the diff command should work.  Once that is calculated then using the cut command and group_by from dplyr will summarize.  If you can be clearer by providing an example output, it would be easier to provide a final solution.

Comment: It's not a data.frame (nor a data.table) although it probably inherits from data.frame. It's whatever the dplyr objects are called which I think is `data_frame`. You should post output from: `dput(object)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think dplyr or data.table is required:

```
df$newEntries <- c(diff(df$ENTRIES),0)
```

(Presumably, the last entry cannot have any number of entries, and so is 0)

EDIT:

Ah, I see you want this for each group so extending the solution:

```
df %>% group_by(DATE,SCP) %>% mutate(newEntries = c(diff(ENTRIES),0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When I run this code newEntries comes back with all 0 values.  Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, you should get the same 0's for akrun's code... his data.table solution is the same as my dplyr one. (He definitely deserves the answer on this one, shift is faster than diff), Is it possible the groups in your dataset contain only one element?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, I used `Entries` rather than `ENTRIES`

Comment: No - I used ENTRIES on my end and it gives me 0s for the entire column.  I tried Akuns Shift solution and I get values (not grouped right - but that's my bad)

Comment: Well, since there's a good answer that encapsulates the gist of mine, I'm going to delete my answer, but that's still very curious, there's not a lot of code up there to go wrong... Does akrun's first data.table solution, the one involving diff work?

Comment: There could be another dplyr "issue" involving group_by breaking the order of the table (which data.table thankfully does not do), so I think this might actually need an arrange step prior to the mutate.

Comment: Akrun's dpyr solution gives me the same column of 0s.  I think you are right and there must be a superseding dplyr issue.  My issue right now with data.table is that it is also masking other package functions I need.

Comment: Don't delete your answer.  Very concise though Akruns is more in depth

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'DATE' and 'SCP' we assign (`:=`) 'newEntries' as the difference of "ENTRIES' and concatenate with 0 (as the `diff` output is of length one less than the number of rows per group)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newEntries := c(diff(ENTRIES),0) , .(DATE, SCP)]
```

`diff` can be slow, so we can also use `shift`

```
setDT(df)[, newEntries :=shift(ENTRIES, type="lead", 
                   fill= ENTRIES[.N])- ENTRIES ,.(DATE, SCP)]
```

---

Or an equivalent code with `dplyr` would be to group by 'DATE', 'SCP' and then use `mutate` to create the 'newEntries' column by taking the difference of the `lead` values of "ENTRIES" (i.e. succeeding values) with that of the current "ENTRIES".  Here, I changed the `default` option as by default the `lead` gives NA as the last entry.  By changing to `ENTRIES[n()]`, we are getting the last value of 'ENTRIES' for each combination of groups so that the difference will be 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(DATE, SCP) %>%
   mutate(newEntries = lead(ENTRIES, default=ENTRIES[n()]) - ENTRIES)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you explain the mutate line under dplyr?  I understand the function but what is "lead(?ENTRIES, default=ENTRIES[n()]) - ENTRIES)"?

Comment: @Windstorm1981  By default, `lead` will return `NA` for the last entry.  By doing `default=ENTRIES[n()]`, we get the last observation of ENTRIES by group, and by doing the difference, we get 0.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the first solution, should be c(diff(ENTRIES),0), shift is cool, I'm using that in future

Comment: @akrun Still not sure I follow.  Could you explain a bit more?  sorry if I'm being dense.  I don't see how the code statement know how to take the lagged difference of the ENTRIES column.  Thx.

Comment: @Windstorm1981  I added some explanation.  To get more info, you can split the code and check the output of `lead` i.e. `df %>% group_by(DATE, SCP) %>% mutate(i1 = lead(ENTRIES), i2 = lead(ENTRIES, default=ENTRIES[n()])`